# wso2is 5.0 - Destiantion attribute is not set for LogoutResponse

Tags: liferay, saml-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Im trying to set up wso2is as an IdP. Liferay acts as SP.

Signing in is done successfully. My actual problem is - there is no 'destination' attribute set in LogoutResponse so liferay saml-portlet is throwing:

```
    14:12:26,779 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-18][BaseSamlStrutsAction:45com.liferay.saml.SamlException: org.opensaml.xml.security.SecurityException: SAML message intended destination (required by binding) was not present
com.liferay.saml.SamlException: org.opensaml.xml.security.SecurityException: SAML message intended destination (required by binding) was not present
    at com.liferay.saml.profile.WebSsoProfileImpl.processResponse(WebSsoProfileImpl.java:166)
    at com.liferay.saml.profile.WebSsoProfileUtil.processResponse(WebSsoProfileUtil.java:50)
    at com.liferay.saml.hook.action.AssertionConsumerServiceAction.doExecute(AssertionConsumerServiceAction.java:38)
```

So here is my actual LogoutRequest:

```
<saml2p:LogoutRequest Destination="https://localhost:9443/samlsso"
    ID="_22d8ba65fc7ffdbc63d9d45ddea3e420ebc53373" IssueInstant="2014-07-30T13:16:33.576Z"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">liferaysamlspdemo</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#_22d8ba65fc7ffdbc63d9d45ddea3e420ebc53373">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>A00CJe+mILdS1J9rofdyDWtO+/M=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>[value]
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>[cert data]
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">xxx</saml2:NameID>
    <saml2p:SessionIndex>436f2982-c96c-4884-a9ea-7b8b4cde13ff</saml2p:SessionIndex>
</saml2p:LogoutRequest>
```

And the corresponding response:

```
<saml2p:LogoutResponse ID="hbkakhdacckapfinfncplppndpkhbpihhnfphjoh"
    InResponseTo="_69f6c1f18217d5626f0a76a1b705138d56e5077f" IssueInstant="2014-07-30T14:12:26.651Z"
    Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
        xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">liferaysamlidpdemo</saml2:Issuer>
    <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <ds:Reference URI="#hbkakhdacckapfinfncplppndpkhbpihhnfphjoh">
                <ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:Transform
                        Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </ds:Transforms>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>35a6HRTd3gbqiGhR2RzkRWn+f04=</ds:DigestValue>
            </ds:Reference>
        </ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:SignatureValue>[value]
        </ds:SignatureValue>
        <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
                <ds:X509Certificate>[cert data]
                </ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
    </ds:Signature>
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </saml2p:Status>
</saml2p:LogoutResponse>
```

Now is that a general wso2is problem and it does not include "destination" attribute to LogoutResponse or am i doeing something wrong. I would be great if i could get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are using `HTTP-POST` binding the standard says:

> If the message is signed, the Destination XML attribute in the root
>   SAML element of the protocol message MUST contain the URL to which the
>   sender has instructed the user agent to deliver the message.

And therefore it would mean that wso2 has a bug.

The Destination attribute is not be required with `HTTP-Artifact` or `SAML SOAP` bindings. In case you use one of these, it would mean that there's a problem on the Liferay side.